# Python Poetry: Where is get-poetry.py?

Tags: python, installation, python-poetry

macOS Mojave 10.14.6
Python 3.7.2

I installed python poetry just like it is in the docs:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python
```

As far as I can tell it went well, besides $POETRY_HOME did not get set.
Something like `<full_path_to_poetry>/poetry --version` works.
Now I would like to try several things mentioned in the documentation with `get-poetry.py`, e.g.

```
python get-poetry.py --preview
```

It turned out I do not have `get-poetry.py` on my hard drive anywhere.
Am I missing steps somewhere? Installing poetry with `pip` or creating a project does not help with the missing `get-poetry.py`

Comment: The docs say "you can download the `get-poetry.py` file and execute it separately" so I suggest trying to do that.

Comment: I see , yes, in PyPy it's mentioned. I was following steps of the official (?) website https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation , it goes into get-poetry.py usage (uninstall in particular) right after installation. Strange

Answer (score 2):

1. in https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation it's not mentioned that you need to download get-poetry.py as a separate step. In https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry it is mentioned. Thanks to [martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) for the quote.
2. As of the problem of $POETRY_HOME not set, that's probably not used any more. Install adds poetry location to $PATH in `~/.bash_profile` so just source it and calling `poetry` will work.

Comment: I can't find any mention of how to download get-poetry.py in the link you shared. Perhaps it would be useful if you copied the instructions here in case the page you link gets edited.

Answer (score 1):

When you follow the official installation docs get-poetry.py is not downloaded but piped directly into the 'python' executable. You can currently download it like this:

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py > get-poetry.py
```

However the use of `get-poetry.py` appears to be in the process of being deprecated so this may change in future.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, from the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation):

> The installer script is available directly at install.python-poetry.org, and is developed in its own repository. The script can be executed directly (i.e. ‘curl python’) or downloaded and then executed from disk (e.g. in a CI environment).

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

Answer (score 1):

The `get-poetry.py` file was removed from `master`, if want to uninstall poetry (that was installed by `get_poetry.py`) you can run the following command:

```
sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/58d2b996354f846c087abbc46ee67bb7fe83f7b5/get-poetry.py | python3 - --uninstall
```

Comment: this saved my day since I had an old version of Poetry that was installed with this script and didn't want to remove manually, thanks!